# Custom folder CT + rich HTML field , unable to add a new custom folder to the list - BUG

Tags: sharepoint-online, folder, richhtmlfield

SharePoint Online
I've created a CT based on folder and added a site column (html field) to it. Then I added the CT to a list but I'm unable to create a new custom folder in the list.

In the newform I get the title and the HTML field up and I'm able to edit info. But when I press save nothing happends (does not create the custom folder in the list/**document library** )

[image: newform]

**Workaround**

1. Create default folder in the list
2. Edit folder (you just created)
3. Change content type then you can add text to the html field and save it...

This must be a bug!

Answer (score 0):

unfortunatly it is not possible to have rich text/html in folder content types.

Comment: I've managed to create a custom folder with HTML field .. but suddenly it stopped working!

Comment: I tried this myself and I did not find a solution. Maybe this approach could help you: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/krichie/2006/11/27/rich-text-column-for-document-libraries-dont-work-as-expected/